# custom GUI app in GNOME, desktop file & app menu

Tags: linux, gnome

I made a custom QML app and a .desktop file for it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=
Terminal=false
Name=ProjectPad
Exec=/home/emmanuel/home/projectpad/.cabal-sandbox/bin/projectpad
Type=Application
Icon=emblem-documents-symbolic.symbolic
```

The desktop file works, I can start the app, however once started in gnome-shell in the app menu and in alt-tab it shows only `Unknown` and a missing icon. The icon is properly displayed in gnome-system-monitor though. I understand that gnome expects the application to register its name a startup using Gtk APIs, however I can't easily do that from a QML app. How can I achieve that gnome will take into account the app name & icon from the desktop file not only at launch time but also later, in alt-tab & app menu?

**EDIT**: I think it might be a problem with the binding to QML that I'm using from Haskell, I've opened [a bug there](http://trac.gekkou.co.uk/hsqml/ticket/34). But it's only a theory... The fact is that according to `xprop`, there is no `WM_CLASS` (not found) nor `WM_Class` (so such atom on any window). I think QML and the HSQML library that I use should ensure that `WM_CLASS` is populated and they don't, that's why I don't get an icon I believe.

Comment: Have you tried using an icon in your home folder (absolute path under .local/share/icons or .icons)?

Comment: the current symbolic icon works in the launcher menu. doesn't work (as with the app name) later once it's launched. I would think it's not related, but i'll try this tonight and report.

Comment: Right, I just tried, but to put a real icon name, absolute path under my home dir, that didn't help. Also a real icon name which is not a symbolic icon... didn't help.

Comment: Maybe it is the same problem one faces to crea a java desktop icon: it is needed to add the StartupWMClass

Comment: I think yes. The bug I opened is related to the fact that the app doesn't set a WM_CLASS X11 property. I don't think I can control it from my code, it should probably be set up from the library.

Comment: You can add it with the (second) result of `xprop WM_CLASS`. Does it help?

Comment: are you saying I can use `xprop` to SET an X11 property? I tried a bit now and failed. It says `unsupported conversion`. Otherwise I see others apps even have their icons in X11 properties, in `_NET_WM_ICON`... Interesting...

Comment: No. I meant to type `xprop WM_Class` and then point to the QML app. You add that information to the .desktop file (which I guess resides in .local/share/applications or your root folder) thus: `StartupWMClass=name-of-the-app-according-to-xprop`. Remember to restart the icon theme

Comment: `xprop WM_Class` will render two names. Use the second one

Comment: Yes but I think the root problem is that the app does not export any such X11 property (I updated the question now). `xprop WM_Class` returns `WM_Class:  no such atom on any window.` and `xprop WM_CLASS` returns `WM_CLASS:  not found.`. So I can't add this property.